# Combine two bookmarklets that changes url AND removes parameters

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, bookmarklet, url-parameters

I'm trying to combine two bookmarklets into one so that it

1. Removes all url parameters (if any)
2. Redirects from one url to a sub domain.

Example:

From

http://www.justsomeurl.com**/cat/article123**?umt=sometimes-theres-a-parameter

To

http://cms.justsomeurl.com/.admin/something/**cat/article123**

I have two separate bookmarklets that does this but I haven't managed to combine them.

```
javascript:location.href = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf("?"));
```

and

```
javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/www\.justsomeurl.com/,'http://cms.justsomeurl.com/.admin/');})()
```

I suspect a delay is needed between step 1 and 2.

I have tried this (and many combos) but it seems only the second function is picked up:

```
javascript: 
    function removeParameter(){ location.href = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf("?"));} ;

(function replace() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/www\.justsomeurl.com/,'http://cms.justsomeurl.com/.admin/');})();
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following bookmarklet must work as needed:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var url = location.href;
    url = url.split("?")[0].replace("www.justsomeurl.com", "cms.justsomeurl.com/.admin/something");
    location.href = url;
})();
```

Comment: Appreciate the help Shugar! It's close but not quite there yet. The bookmarklet now works excellent WITH a url parameter, but it doesn't work at all when there's NO url parameter. I need it to work in both scenarios.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million for helping out!